# Apache Ignite production configuration settings

Tags: c#, ignite, gridgain

What are the recommended production configuration settings for apache ignite?
Are there any best practices to follow?

Comment: read the documentation: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/dotnetdoc/api/

Answer (score 1):

In general, it depends on your requirements and concrete environment, but you can check official [performance recommendations](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/perf-and-troubleshooting/general-perf-tips) and adjust the settings accordingly if required.